# Is there a circular dependency between an collection and its iterator?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, iterator, design-patterns

An *iterator* definitely has to know about the *collection* that it has to iterate. Do the *collection* also have to know about its *iterator*? Is the dependency one way or both ways? If the collection has knowledge about a particular iterator implementation then it may not be possible to have different iterator strategies for the same collection. This is my thought. Am I right or did I get it completely wrong?

The GoF book has this diagram for the *Iterator pattern*:

[image]

I think it implies a circular dependency. I am not sure about the dotted lines from `List` to `LisIterator` and `SkipList` to `SkipListIterator`.

P.S: I deal in Java everyday but may be it is more of a design question than being specific to a particular language.

Comment: Did you look at the source code for Java's collections to see how they've done it? That would probably lend some insight into your design question.

Comment: In C++ one could use: std::vector<Entity*>::iterator Which makes me assume vector has a namespace containing iterator.

Comment: Yes, there is, and it's okay. The point is that the iterator *interface* abstracts from how to iterate over the collection. The iterator *implementation* handles this. Essentially, you can consider an iterator implementation as part of the collection's implementation. The important thing is that there is no such dependency between the interfaces. (I.e. you don't need to care what sort of collection, if it even is a collection, a given `Iterator` works on.)

Comment: @millimoose that means I can not replace one iterator implementation with another?

Comment: @Geek That question doesn't make sense. Why would you ever want to? That's not the point of the abstraction. Which iterator implementation to use is up to the collection itself. The iterator *isn't meant to be* an extension point (a specific type of abstraction) of the collection, it just hides a specific detail about the implementation of the collection.

Comment: @millimoose say I want to traverse a list backwards and not forward. isn't that a valid use-case?

Comment: @Geek You could hypothethically have a method `List.reverseIterator()` which would once again return just an `Iterator`, just an implementation thereof that can walk the given collection in reverse. You could also invent all sorts of APIs to let you tell a collection what "flavour" of iterator you want and maybe get it back. Except that's just not how the API is designed.

Comment: @Geek To counter your example: what if the collection is a "lazy" one with an infinite number of elements? Or if it represents lines read from standard input? These are all situations you'd have to handle in a much more complicated API. And seeing as you can't guarantee that a given "iteration strategy" works on any given collection, this would be leaking a bunch of implementation details of a collection into the iterator API.

Comment: @Geek And remember that a collection **always** has to have knowledge about what iterator implementation is appropriate. (E.g. fetch items by index, follow a linked list, traverse a tree, skip empty buckets in a hash...) Your desired "iteration strategy" (variations on the *observed* behaviour of an iterator), and Java's notion of an `Iterator` implementation (internal details of how this behaviour is achieved) are two different concepts entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all but some specialized implementations the collection does not need to know about the iterator.

The dotted line in this case signifies instantiation.  If you have the gang of 4 book, the explantion is given on page 15, section 1.6.

Specifically, an iterator is created by the CreateIterator method, in Java iterator().

Geek Humor:  tell people your Jersey Shore name is "THE INSTANTATION"

Comment: What would be those specialized implementations. Can you throw an example ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not cyclic by necessity. This is made clear by the fact that you can implement a new iterator for a given data structure anytime.

For example, if you need an iterator that first yields the even numbered elements of an ArrayList in ascending order and then the odd numbered items in descending order, there is nothing that can block you from just writing that stuff.